# Ubuntu Server 12.04: Write Files via Samba with Group Ownership

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, samba, groups

I have a shared samba drive set up on my virtual machine guest running Ubuntu Server 12.04.

```
\\ubuntu\www
```

The file path /var/www has the permissions `www-data:www-data` set up.
My user name abe is part of the group `www-data`.

I am using a Windows XP Host machine and I do my development using my host machine, but I just save the files to the samba shared `\\ubuntu\www`.

When I do so, the file owner gets set to my username abe, which is expected...

**Question:** is there a way to set up my samba shared at \ubuntu\www to write to my group (www-data) instead of my username?

Here is what my samba configuration file (/etc/ looks like:

```
[www]
comment = Apache Document Home
path = /var/www/
writable = yes
force group = www-data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a little confused. If you want the owner to be set to `www-data:www-data`, then add

```
force user = www-data
```

Or are you saying that the files are not being created with the correct group name (www-data)?

Comment: I want the files to be written as www-data:www-data instead of abe:www-data

Comment: Okay, then my answer will achieve this. Since you set the user owner already to www-data, the www-data user already exists.

Comment: Thanks, I tried writing a file from my host machine and the permissions were set to www-data:www-data

Answer (score 1):

```
chown abe:www-data /var/www
chmod g+s /var/www
```

It shall force the group of the future created files :)

Comment: This would just to "force" the group of future created files, to be the same as the group-ownership.

Since your question said that "it's okay" if the file have your user as owner, i thought that just the group shall be "forced" ;)